# Why are my specs while using Guard so slow?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, automated-tests, guard

When I run my specs using just `spork`, I get quite a significant performance increase

```
$ time rspec .
.....

Finished in 11.39 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures

real    0m11.780s
user    0m10.318s
sys     0m1.180s
```

and with spork

```
$ time rspec . --drb
.....

Finished in 107.24 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures

real    0m1.968s
user    0m0.488s
sys     0m0.095s
```

which is really awesome. But once I put guard into play, it seems that everything runs so slow, as if there was no spork at all.

```
$ guard
Guard is now watching at '/Users/darth/projects/scvrush'
Starting Spork for RSpec 
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Spork server for RSpec successfully started
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
.....

Finished in 10.77 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures
```

even if I don't look at the `Finished in 10.77 seconds`, I can count at least 6-8 seconds every time it tries to run a spec, even for just one model.

I did some [minor edits to the Guardfile](https://gist.github.com/1324433), such as `:wait => 120`, but that should only affect when `guard` is starting up.

Comment: I've never used Guard, but where are you passing `--drb` when using Guard?  Have you added `--drb` to your `.rspec` file?

Comment: @d11wtq there's a guard-spork gem, which tells Guard to start an instance of spork and then all the specs with it, so it should work out of the box ... or I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the --drb option for rspec in your Guardfile, like this:

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => '--drb' do
 ...
end
```